# Android: mediaplayer create

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have this code:

```
package com.example.pr;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Audio{

    MediaPlayer mp;

    public void playClick(){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Audio.this, R.raw.click);  
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

I have an error in "create" with this message "The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (Audio, int)"

why?

Comment: audio is just a class not an activity so that audio.this wont contribute to context

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MediaPlayer.create() needs a *Context* as first parameter. Pass in the current *Activity* and it should work.

try:

```
public void playClick(Context context){
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.click);  
    mp.start();
}
```

in your Activity:

```
audio = new Audio();
...
audio.playClick(this);
```

but don't forget to call release on the MediaPlayer instance once the sound has finished, or you'll get an exception.

However, for playing short clicks using a *SoundPool* might be better anyway.

Comment: Audio is not an activity, it's a separate class that I use to manage audio, in fact I pass Audio.this

Comment: Late answer: you need an Android Context to pass. not your Audio class. So either add a Context parameter to the playClick method or have each Activity have their own instance of the Audio class with the Activity Context passed in the constructor.

Comment: can anyone tell me how can i add 2 raw files in mediaplayer.create

Comment: If you want to play two sounds in parallel you have to create two MediaPlayers

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Audio{

    MediaPlayer mp;
Context context;

     public Audio(Context ct){
     this.context = ct;
}
    public void playClick(){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.click);  
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    }
```

From your Activity:

```
Audio audio = new Audio(YourActivity.getApplicationContext());
audio.playClick();
```

Comment: create already does the prepare.  `MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.click).start();`