# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: java, android

When only one button is created everything runs fine but whenever I create one method for different buttons,these errors shows up:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

Kindly Help.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.openRawResourceFd(ResourcesImpl.java:287)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:1263)
                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:931)
                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:914)
                      at com.example.chakshu.griddemo.MainActivity.pressed(MainActivity.java:26)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

This is my activity_main.xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/activity_main"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.example.chakshu.griddemo.MainActivity">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="pressed"/>
    <Button
    android:text="B"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="pressed"/>
    <Button
        android:text="C"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="pressed"/>
    <Button
        android:text="D"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="pressed"/>
    <Button
        android:text="e"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="pressed"/>

    <Button
        android:text="f"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="pressed"/>

    <Button
        android:text="g"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_row="3"
       android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="pressed"/>
    <Button
        android:text="h"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="pressed"/>
       </GridLayout>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity.java code:

```
 package com.example.chakshu.griddemo;

 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
   public void pressed(View view) {

    int id = view.getId();
    String ourId = "";

    ourId = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);

    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(ourId, "raw", 
    "com.example.chakshu.griddemo");

    MediaPlayer mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceId);
    mplayer.start();


    }
```

Comment: please add your related code to the question.

Comment: added sir.kindly help

Answer (score 0):

I think the real error is in the middle, the line `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 at` suggests it can't find the resource you passed in.

The resource you pass in would typically be something like `R.raw.my_resource_name`

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#create(android.content.Context,%20int)) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154951/android-mediaplayer-create).

Comment: `R.raw.value` is just an integer. The code is trying to dynamically build that value using getResources()

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I know that. It is apparently failing to find the resource, but without seeing the XML or resources it's hard to say much else, or to know if there's a specific reason for building it up dynamically vs. just using the integer.

Comment: Sure. I think the main problem is that the clicked view id will rarely (if ever) match the raw resource id.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is no valid resource ID was found inside the following code:

```
public void pressed(View view) {

    int id = view.getId();
    String ourId = "";

    ourId = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);

    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(ourId, "raw", 
    "com.example.chakshu.griddemo");

    ...
}
```

Where [getResourceEntryName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName(int)) will throwing `Resources.NotFoundException` because the id does not exist and [getIdentifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) will return 0 if no valid resource ID not found.

So, update your click listener method to something like this:

```
public void pressed(View view) {

    int id = view.getId();

    try {
      String ourId = getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);
      int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(ourId, "raw", getPackageName());

      if(resId == 0) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "error, no found raw");
      } else {
        MediaPlayer mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceId);
        mplayer.start();
      }
    } catch(NotFoundException e) {
      Log.d("MainActivity", "error, no found resource = " + e.toString);
    }


}
```

---

Instead depending by the button ID name, try using `android:tag` and `[getTag][3]` method. For example, with the following button:

```
<Button
    android:text="A"
    android:tag="raw_resource_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:onClick="pressed"/>
```

And then, you can use the following code:

```
public void pressed(View view) {

  String resName = (String) view.getTag();
  int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", getPackageName());

  if(resId == 0) {
     Log.d("MainActivity", "error, no found raw");
  } else {
     MediaPlayer mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceId);
     mplayer.start();
  }
}
```